# The module has not been deployed [netbeans+glassfish]

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

i am developping a project base on J2EE EJB JSF, database is MYsql, the project works very well last week. but today, it can't be deployed when i run it. here are some exception:

```
   Initial deploying ECOM to C:\Users\John624\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PromoCoupon\ECOM\dist\gfdeploy\ECOM
Completed initial distribution of ECOM
Initializing...
invalid header field name: Exception Description
C:\Users\John624\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PromoCoupon\ECOM\nbproject\build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

**Glassfish:**

```
   <code> SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method
SEVERE:   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [ECOM-ejbPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7158] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery [Adresse.maxId] from entity class [class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.NullExpression cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:180)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:431)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [ECOM-ejbPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7158] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery [Adresse.maxId] from entity class [class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.NullExpression cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1950)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1941)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:922)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:150)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:239)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:150)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [ECOM-ejbPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7158] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery [Adresse.maxId] from entity class [class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.NullExpression cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7158] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery [Adresse.maxId] from entity class [class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.NullExpression cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorProcessingNamedQuery(ValidationException.java:824)
    at org.
SEVERE:   Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE:   eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata.process(NamedQueryMetadata.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processQueries(MetadataProject.java:1628)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.addNamedQueries(MetadataProcessor.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1894)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.NullExpression cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariable
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.DeclarationResolver$DeclarationVisitor.visit(DeclarationResolver.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.RangeVariableDeclaration.accept(RangeVariableDeclaration.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.DeclarationResolver$DeclarationVisitor.visit(DeclarationResolver.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.IdentificationVariableDeclaration.accept(IdentificationVariableDeclaration.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.DeclarationResolver$DeclarationVisitor.visit(DeclarationResolver.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.FromClause.accept(FromClause.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.DeclarationResolver.populateImp(DeclarationResolver.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.DeclarationResolver.populate(DeclarationResolver.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.JPQLQueryHelper$DescriptorCollector.collectDescriptors(JPQLQueryHelper.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.JPQLQueryHelper$DescriptorCollector.visit(JPQLQueryHelper.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.FromClause.accept(FromClause.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.AbstractSelectStatement.acceptChildren(AbstractSelectStatement.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.SelectStatement.acceptChildren(SelectStatement.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.AbstractTraverseChildrenVisitor.visit(AbstractTraverseChildrenVisitor.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.AnonymousExpressionVisitor.visit(AnonymousExpressionVisitor.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.SelectStatement.accept(SelectStatement.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.JPQLExpression.acceptChildren(JPQLExpression.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.AbstractTraverseChildrenVisitor.visit(AbstractTraverseChildrenVisitor.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.AnonymousExpressionVisitor.visit(AnonymousExpressionVisitor.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.JPQLExpression.accept(JPQLExpression.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.JPQLQueryHelper.getClassDescriptors(JPQLQueryHelper.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata.addJPAQuery(NamedQueryMetadata.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata.process(NamedQueryMetadata.java:192)
    ... 54 more
<code>
```

**entity bean**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author John624
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Adresse")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.maxId", query = "SELECT max(idAdresse) FROM Adresse"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findByIdAdresse", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a WHERE a.idAdresse = :idAdresse"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findByNumEtRue", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a WHERE a.numEtRue = :numEtRue"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findByComple", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a WHERE a.comple = :comple"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findByCodePostale", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a WHERE a.codePostale = :codePostale"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findByVille", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a WHERE a.ville = :ville"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findByPays", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a WHERE a.pays = :pays"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.findByDateModif", query = "SELECT a FROM Adresse a WHERE a.dateModif = :dateModif")})
public class Adresse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idAdresse")
    private Long idAdresse;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "numEtRue")
    private String numEtRue;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "comple")
    private String comple;
    @Size(max = 5)
    @Column(name = "codePostale")
    private String codePostale;
    @Size(max = 35)
    @Column(name = "ville")
    private String ville;
    @Size(max = 35)
    @Column(name = "pays")
    private String pays;
    @Column(name = "dateModif")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateModif;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adrU")
    private Collection<Utilisateur> utilisateurCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adrRecep")
    private Collection<Livraison> livraisonCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "adrE")
    private Collection<Entreprise> entrepriseCollection;

    public Adresse() {
    }

    public Adresse(Long idAdresse) {
        this.idAdresse = idAdresse;
    }

    public Long getIdAdresse() {
        return idAdresse;
    }

    public void setIdAdresse(Long idAdresse) {
        this.idAdresse = idAdresse;
    }

    public String getNumEtRue() {
        return numEtRue;
    }

    public void setNumEtRue(String numEtRue) {
        this.numEtRue = numEtRue;
    }

    public String getComple() {
        return comple;
    }

    public void setComple(String comple) {
        this.comple = comple;
    }

    public String getCodePostale() {
        return codePostale;
    }

    public void setCodePostale(String codePostale) {
        this.codePostale = codePostale;
    }

    public String getVille() {
        return ville;
    }

    public void setVille(String ville) {
        this.ville = ville;
    }

    public String getPays() {
        return pays;
    }

    public void setPays(String pays) {
        this.pays = pays;
    }

    public Date getDateModif() {
        return dateModif;
    }

    public void setDateModif(Date dateModif) {
        this.dateModif = dateModif;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Utilisateur> getUtilisateurCollection() {
        return utilisateurCollection;
    }

    public void setUtilisateurCollection(Collection<Utilisateur> utilisateurCollection) {
        this.utilisateurCollection = utilisateurCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Livraison> getLivraisonCollection() {
        return livraisonCollection;
    }

    public void setLivraisonCollection(Collection<Livraison> livraisonCollection) {
        this.livraisonCollection = livraisonCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Entreprise> getEntrepriseCollection() {
        return entrepriseCollection;
    }

    public void setEntrepriseCollection(Collection<Entreprise> entrepriseCollection) {
        this.entrepriseCollection = entrepriseCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idAdresse != null ? idAdresse.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Adresse)) {
            return false;
        }
        Adresse other = (Adresse) object;
        if ((this.idAdresse == null && other.idAdresse != null) || (this.idAdresse != null && !this.idAdresse.equals(other.idAdresse))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Adresse[ idAdresse=" + idAdresse + " ]";
    }

}
```

**session bean**

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package session;

```
import entities.Adresse;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author John624
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AdresseManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ECOM-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Adresse> getAllAdresses() {
        Query query=em.createNamedQuery("Adresse.findAll");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public Adresse update(Adresse adresse) {
        return em.merge(adresse);
    }

    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }

    public Long nextId(){
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Adresse.maxId");
        long res;
        res = query.getResultList().indexOf(0)+1;
        return res;
    }
}
```

**JSF managedbean**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package managedbeans;

import entities.Adresse;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import session.AdresseManager;

/**
 *
 * @author John624
 */
@Named(value="adresseMBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AdresseMBean implements Serializable{

    private List<Adresse> adresses;
    private Adresse adresse;
    @EJB
    private AdresseManager adresseManager;

    public AdresseMBean() {
        adresse=new Adresse();
        adresseManager = new AdresseManager();
    }
     /** 
     * returns customer list for display in a datatable DataTable 
     * @return 
     */  
    public List<Adresse> getAdresses() {  
        if((adresses == null) || (adresses.isEmpty()))
            adresses = adresseManager.getAllAdresses();  
        return adresseManager.getAllAdresses();  
    }  

//    public void refresh() {  
//        tousLesComptes = compteBancaireFacade.findAll();  
//    }  

    /** 
     * returns details of a customer. Useful for displaying in a form a customer's details 
     * @return 
     */  
    public Adresse getDetails() {  
        return adresse;  
    }  

    /** 
     * Action handler - Called when a line in the table is clicked 
     * @param adresse 
     * @return 
     */  
    public String showDetails(Adresse adresse) {  
        this.adresse = adresse;  
        return "AdresseDetails"; // will display CustomerDetails.xml JSF page  
    }  

    /** 
     * Action handler - update the customer model in the database. 
     * called when one press the update button in the form 
     * @return 
     */  
    public String  update() {  
        System.out.println("###UPDATE###");  
        adresse = adresseManager.update(adresse);  
        return "AdresseList"; // will display the customer list in a table  
    }  

    /** 
     * Action handler - returns to the list of customers in the table 
     */  
    public String list() {  
        System.out.println("###LIST###");  
        return "AdresseList";  
    }  

    public void update(Adresse adrU) {
        System.out.println("###UPDATE###");  
        adresseManager.update(adrU);  
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As indicated by the following exception stacktrace

```
Exception Description: Error encountered when building the @NamedQuery [Adresse.maxId] from entity class [class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata].
```

the problem is here :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.maxId", query = "SELECT max(idAdresse) FROM Adresse"),
```

To solve the problem, try this instead:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Adresse.maxId", query = "SELECT max(a.idAdresse) FROM Adresse a"),
```

Comment: Thank you, i found the probleme. its the probleme of query.

Comment: SELECT max(a.idAdresse) FROM Adresse a")

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case it was a missing whitespace before the where statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try out these steps:

1. Undeploy the application from glassfish server.
2. Restart the glassfish server.
3. Restart netbeans.
4. Again deploy your application on the glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove adresseManager = new AdresseManager(); from your AdresseMBean class.

@EJB injects and creates already the object.

Then try to redeploy the project and put a debug breakpoint in getAdresses method to see if adresseManager object isn't null or do a poor Sysout.

If you want to initialize services on starting of a managed bean, you'll need to use @PostConstruct annotation on a custom public method inside managed bean and code your  initialisation there (eg. loading entity list from db).

Hope it will help you.

PS : Excuse my mistakes for english language, i'm French.

PS2 : I've not seen that it was working before, so it is perhaps a deployment problem !